# Doctrine - How to bind array to the SQL?

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, symfony

My SQL looks something like this:

```
$sql = "select * from user where id in (:userId) and status = :status";

$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':userId', $accounts, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
$stmt->bindValue(':status', 'declined');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But it returns:

> An exception occurred while executing (...)
>
> with params
>   [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,14], "declined"]
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion

I cannot user `queryBuilder` because my real SQL is more complicated (ex. contains joined select, unions and so on)

Comment: Can you use foreach?

`foreach($accounts as $key => $val) { $stmt->bindValue(':userId', $val); }`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can't use prepared statements with arrays simply because sql itself does not support arrays.  Which is a real shame.  Somewhere along the line you actually need to determine if your data contains say three items and emit a IN (?,?,?).  The Doctrine ORM entity manager does this for you automatically.

Fortunately, the DBAL has you covered.  You just don't use bind or prepare.  The manual has an example: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion

In your case it would look something like:

```
$sql = "select * from user where id in (?) and status = ?";
$values = [$accounts,'declined'];
$types = [Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY, \PDO::PARAM_STR];
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery($sql,$values,$types);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The above code is untested but you should get the idea. (Make sure you `use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;` for `Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY`)

Note for people using named parameters:

If you are using named parameters (`:param` instead of `?`), you should respect the parameter names when providing types. For example:

```
$sql = "select * from user where id in (:accounts) and status = :status";
$values = ['accounts' => $accounts, 'status' => 'declined'];
$types = ['accounts' => Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY, 'status' => \PDO::PARAM_STR];
```

Comment: ok but in this situation I need to be careful to bind data in the right order :( This is "not cool" :\

Comment: I understand the concern and named parameters are nice but think about it, you only have two parameters.  Not difficult to keep them in order.  When dealing with queries with a larger number of parameters, I use the dbal query builder to generate the sql and basically add values to my $values array as I go along.  So it's not so bad once you get used to it.  And it saves you from having to decide what the parameters should be named in the first place.  Naming is always hard.

Comment: But mu real SQL is more complex http://pastebin.com/1JiRHFdc, any ideas how to do this 'right'? It will also contains more variables and in where clausure if user decide to more filter results

Comment: Start by using the DBAL query builder.  In this case, you would have two $qb objects.  One for the inner select and one for the outer select.  Use $qb->toSQL() to feed the inner select into the outer one.  Then it's just a question of keeping your $values and $types array in sync.  As far as additional additional where clauses, maybe take a look here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/multi-word-like-prepared-statement-for-pdo-query/223738/17?u=ahundiak.

Comment: First decide if you are using DQL or SQL.  Big difference.  For SQL use $conn->createQueryBuilder();

Comment: I have changed it to this: http://pastebin.com but now I have an error `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 52 near 'SELECT r0_.id': Error: Class 'SELECT' is not defined.`. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I think we are getting beyond the scope of a stack overflow discussion.  Stop for a moment and think about what you are doing.  It's just sql manipulation.  If your original query worked then it's just a question of reproducing it step by step.  Testing as you go along.

Comment: How valid would this be to be run on a master DB where it has slaves in place on a production environment?

Comment: The funny thing about the answer "sql itself does not support arrays" is that I've never seen anyone literally ask about or try to put arrays into SQL, they're just trying to convert the array values to a SQL statement; why Doctrine or PDO wasn't programmed to take an array and convert its values to a statement like `WHERE whatever IN (v1, v2, v3)`, I don't know, but we have to be careful that we're not answering the wrong question. I can jerry-rig my code to do that, but it's a PITA, and I'm tired of writing custom PITA code for things that should already exist in libraries.

Comment: @SteveExdia I don't completely understand your comment on this 5+ year old answer.  Doctrine does indeed handle arrays.  Kind of the whole point of the answer.

Comment: @Cerad The age alone of an answer is irrelevant; what matters is if the answer is still relevant, as in, useful (in whole or part) to anyone. Otherwise, do you think 5+ years is too old for answers and they should be removed? My comment was in relation to `bindValue` only allowing array format for positional parameters, otherwise a rewrite of the code is needed to instead use executeQuery; this is PITA, and of course an unnecessary limitation from PDO and Doctrine. My comment still applies; the conversion should have already existed in PDO or at least Doctrine. Half-ass implementation is silly

Comment: There seems to be a `\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType::INTEGER` type see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion

Comment: this does not work in dbal >3.6, it returns "array to string conversion" with ArrayParameterType and executeQuery() does not allow 1+ arguments

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to the `:param` syntax where order does not matter, you have to do a bit of extra work, but I'll show you an easier way to bind the parameters:

```
// store all your parameters in one array
$params = array(
    ':status' => 'declined'
);

// then, using your arbitrary array of id's ...
$array_of_ids = array(5, 6, 12, 14);

// ... we're going to build an array of corresponding parameter names
$id_params = array();
foreach ($array_of_ids as $i => $id) {
    // generate a unique name for this parameter
    $name = ":id_$i"; // ":id_0", ":id_1", etc.

    // set the value
    $params[$name] = $id;

    // and keep track of the name
    $id_params[] = $name;
}

// next prepare the parameter names for placement in the query string
$id_params = implode(',', $id_params); // ":id_0,:id_1,..."
$sql = "select * from user where id in ($id_params) and status = :status";
```

In this case we end up with:
`"select * from user where id in (:id_0,:id_1,:id_2,:id_3) and status = :status"`

```
// now prepare your statement like before...
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

// ...bind all the params in one go...
$stmt->execute($params);

// ...and get your results!
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

---

This approach will also work with an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap them in an array

```
$stmt->bindValue(':userId', array($accounts), array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY));
```

http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion

**edit**

I should have elaborated more.  You cannot bind an array like that, dont prepare the sql execute directly as  the example in the docs.

```
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN (?)',
array(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)),
array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY));
```

> You cannot bind an array of values into a single prepared statement parameter

Comment: I don't think so... `Warning: PDOStatement::bindValue() expects parameter 3 to be integer, array given`. I am using `prepare` method, not `executeQuery`