# Binding dynamic array parameter values for SQL with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

To avoid SQL injection with MS SQL Server and Node.js, I typically bind parameters, with something like the following:

```
let pool = await sql.connect(config)
await pool.request()
  .input('ID', sql.Int, ID)
  .input('Name', sql.NVarChar(100), Name)
  .query(`UPDATE Table SET Name = @Name WHERE ID = @ID;`)
```

However, sometimes I have an array of dynamically varying length that I need to supply to a query.

So for instance, I might have a list of references that I want to pull data for. Example

```
const references = ['B1', 'C2', 'D4', 'Z8']; // Sample, but number of entries can be variable
```

And I'd like to do something like this (with pseudo code):

```
let pool = await sql.connect(config)
await pool.request()
  .input('ReferenceList', sql.NVarChar(5), references) // but can't because this is an array
  .query(`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Reference = IN(@ReferenceList);`)
```

I would think this would be a fairly common scenario; what have I missed that I'm not seeing such functionality standard?

For example, a non-parameter binding method would be: (example only - risky to use in internet-facing production systems)

```
  var references_clause = ""
  if(references && references.length){
    references.forEach(function (item) {
      references_clause += "'"+item+"',"
    });
  } else {
    references_clause += "'NA'" // If length false
  }
  references_clause = references_clause.replace(/,(\s+)?$/, '')

let pool = await sql.connect(config)
    await pool.request()
      .query(`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Reference = IN(@references_clause);`)
```

Other frameworks / languages have some methods for this (e.g. [Doctrine - How to bind array to the SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209686/doctrine-how-to-bind-array-to-the-sql)) what is the recommended method for Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer that this can be done with the tagged template literal support.

```
const pool = new ConnectionPool(config);
const req = pool.request();
const query = req.query`select * from [table] where id in (${[1,2,3]})`
query.then((res) => console.log(res);
```

Source:
https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/1575#issuecomment-1798341849